# API printer point

Tags: php, api

I would like to introduce the api printer point in my application to be able to use a remote printer and I found a library of this API but I did not understand how to use it:
this is the library

```
    <?php function Print_point($imprimante,$message) {
// id customer Printer Point
$sid = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

$data = array('sid' => $sid,'token' => $token,'params'  => array('printer_uid' => $imprimante,'printer_msg' => $message));
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.expedy.fr/api/print");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close ($ch);

return $result;
}
?>
```

and this is an example of use

```
 <?php

// Preparation
include "printer_point_lib.php";

$imprimante = "XXXXXXXXX";

// Your message
$msg = "Hello World !";

// To Print
Print_point($imprimante,$msg);

?>
```

I would like to know:
what i'm going to put in $ sid, $ token, CURLOPT_URL, and $imprimante
thank you !

Comment: Is there no documentation that comes with the library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be better off reading the [library documentation](https://www.printer-point.com/api). From what I can see, all you need to do is supply it with your printer ID `$imprimante` and the message you want to print `$msg`, and that's it. I don't think the API requires you to look inside the class and methods. Here's the example listed in the docs:

```
include "printer_point_lib.php";

// Your printer unique id
$imprimante = "123456789";

// Your message
$msg = "Hello World !";

Print_point($imprimante,$msg);
```

Comment: do I need to customize the library and put a $sid and $token that will allow the library to act on my application?

Comment: @ArthurDayne, I am not familiar enough (or at all really) with the library to say. Try without first, if it doesn't work, and you _have_ an sID and token, enter them.

Comment: Thank you very much Dearsina